# Replace all the same words in mongoDB using REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongo-shell

Im trying, in mongoDB using mongosh,to replace all the words that i select in a collection for others.

Example, I have this:

```
_id:12345678901
name:"Peter Parker"
profession:"Superhero"

_id:12345678902
name:"Peter Parker"
profession:"Journalist"

_id:12345678902
name:"Hulk"
profession:"Software Developer"
```

And I want to replace all the "Peter Parker" with "Superman" in a collection called "firstList" to get this:

```
_id:12345678901
name:"Superman"
profession:"Superhero"

_id:12345678902
name:"Superman"
profession:"Journalist"

_id:12345678902
name:"Hulk"
profession:"Software Developer"
```

Im trying this, but it doesnt work:

```
db.firstList.replace({
  "name": {
    "$regex": "(/( |^)Peter Parker\b/g, "$Superman")"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your data you don't need `regex`, you can use the word into find stage as it is.

You can use an aggregation query into update using `[]` like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "name": {
    "$regex": "Peter Parker"
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "name": {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": "$name",
          "find": "Peter Parker",
          "replacement": "Superman"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HRMaqwAyKRU)

By the way, you can use the regex into `find` object if you want. But if you want to match the entire word "Peter Parker" you can use without regex.